# how to change value from select dropdown with just classname in javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

how do i change value from a select down, when there is just a class name ? 
lik this one?

```
<select class="listbox">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

i need to set the value from 10 to 20
can some one plese help and explain?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

jQuery example:

```
$('.listbox').val('20')
```

Or could be easily rewritten to pure JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('listbox')[0].value = '20'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it more then once, you could create a clean routine

```
<script>

    function changeVal(oldval, newval)
    {
        var options = document.getElementsByClassName('listbox')[0].options;
            for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++)
            {
                if (options[i].value == oldval)
                {
                    options[i].value = newval;
                }
                // Just for test
                console.log(i+'|'+options[i].value);
            }
    }

</script>

<select class="listbox">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<br>
<a href="#"onclick="changeVal(10, 20)">change</a>
```